# play framework, when does the method stop executing?

Tags: scala, playframework

```
@Singleton
class DeliveryPartnerController @Inject()(deliveryPartnerService: DeliveryPartnerService)
  extends Controller {
  def getDeliveryPartners() = Action { implicit request =>    
    Ok("")
    BadRequest("") // Is this code reachable?
  }
}
```

In the above method, does the method stop executing after `Ok()` is called?

Comment: It is, compiler doesn't care. It just expects a correct type of *last expression* you want to return from method. I guess you could run it and check. You'll maybe get a warning that the first expression isn't used...

Comment: So in Scala the last statement of a block will be the return value. Therefore Ok is just a value that is going to be skipped, and BadRequest will be the return value of the function `(Request) => Result`

Answer (score 3):

Just like in normal Scala, the statement at the end of a block is what is returned, i.e. in this case `BadRequest` is returned. Unless `Ok` for some reason contains side-effects, which I doubt it does, the `Ok()` function call in your example doesn't actually do anything. It will exectute, then `BadRequest` will execute, and the result of that call will be returned. For quick and easy error handling you could wrap `Ok` with `Try()`, and then substitute it for the `BadRequest` on exception with `getOrElse()`, or `recover()` should you need a bit more advanced error handling: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/util/Try.html

Answer (score 0):

Also see the [The Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) 6.11:

> A block expression `{s1; ...; sn; e}` is constructed from a sequence of block statements `s1,...,sn` and a final expression `e`

In your case, the final expression `e` is `BadRequest("")`